# classify the values inside array list inside list in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to develop a method which receives a List of ArrayList and classify the array list inside it based on the object value. Then, return array list that contains the objects have 1 in their FirstChoice.

the data structure in my code is that

the List has n number of ArrayList, the ArrayList has 24 objects. each object has 3 elements and FirstChoice is one of these elements.

The problem of my code is the output not as i expect , it seems to be just stick with one value and repeat it for the whole list. could you please help me to fix that

```
    ArrayList<HH> TestMethods(List<ArrayList<HH>> s) {
        ArrayList<HH> scenario = new ArrayList<HH>();
        for (ArrayList<HH> d : s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) {
                if (s.get(i).get(i).FirstChoice == 1) {

                    scenario.add(s.get(i).get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        return scenario;

    }
```

Comment: Replace `s.get(i)` by `d`. You could also do another foreach loop for `d` values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that when you are looping over the list `s`, you are actually never using the current element `d`.

Some other comments on your code:

- Prefer returning a `List` instead of an `ArrayList`.
- Name your methods and variables according to Java naming conventions (`testMethods` instead of `TestMethods`, `firstChoice` instead of `FirstChoice`)
- Be consistent in the way you write loops: use foreach or an index but keep to the same style.

```
List<HH> testMethods(List<ArrayList<HH>> s) {
    List<HH> scenario = new ArrayList<HH>();
    for (ArrayList<HH> d : s) {
        for (HH hh : d) {
            if (hh.firstChoice == 1) {
                scenario.add(hh);
            }
        }
    }
    return scenario;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes are on these lines `if (s.get(i).get(i).FirstChoice == 1) {` and `scenario.add(s.get(i).get(i));` as you aren't actually user inner list `d`.
You're referencing the `i'th` element of the `i'th` list of `s`, when I think you want the `i'th` element of `d` where `d` is a list from `s`.

```
ArrayList<HH> TestMethods(List<ArrayList<HH>> s) {
    ArrayList<HH> scenario = new ArrayList<HH>();
    for (ArrayList<HH> d : s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) {

            int item = d.get(i).FirstChoice;

            if (item == 1) {

                scenario.add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return scenario;

}
```

Comment: This does not compile: `d.get(i).FirstChoice` is probably an int given the OP's code, not a `HH`.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer to reflect this, as well as added a more thorough explanation.